# Xpath variable and pagination

Tags: python, selenium, pagination

Hi I'm trying to write a code for python selenium where the driver automatically clicks next page. The problem is that there is no next page link text and pagination is only available via full xpath

Here's the code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pagination-div-id"]/li[%r]/a' % (2))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Where I've placed the "%r" determines the page number. My question: how can I loop through more than one page? (there are 1000 of them). I can't find an answer anywhere. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: why use javascript to click on something when you can use selenium's click function?

Comment: popping modal intercepts with the value i want to click

Comment: You seem to be deleting your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62422542/navigating-through-multiple-pages-without-next-xpath) and raising the same question again and again.

Comment: Yes, because you hid my question and I didn't find an answer to the similar question you linked me to

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like:

```py
for page in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="pagination-div-id"]/li'):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", page.find_element_by_xpath('./a'))
```

Comment: Loops through one page and then I get the following message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document